Terminal singularities of fibers vs total space
Suppose $f\colon X \to Y$ is a flat map of complex varieties (or more generally DM stacks?). Suppose every fiber has at most terminal singularities and that $Y$ is smooth. Under what conditions is it known whether  $X$ also has at most terminal singularities?
Basically, I'm wondering if there are results similar to Elkik's theorem from 1978 for rational singularities (Elkik's theorem also implies that if $X$ is a locally complete intersection scheme, then the fibers having at most canonical singularities implies $X$ does as well).

In your situation, $X$ has at most terminal singularities, at least when $X$ and $Y$ are complex varieties. To make the induction a bit easier, I will state the result as follows:
Theorem. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a flat finite type morphism of integral schemes locally essentially of finite type over a field $k$ of equal characteristic zero. Suppose that $Y$ is regular and that all closed fibers of $f$ have at most terminal singularities. Then, $X$ has at most terminal singularities.
Proof. Replacing $Y$ by $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y})$ for all $y \in Y$, we may reduce to the case when $Y$ is the spectrum of a regular local ring essentially of finite type over $k$. Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d$ be a regular system of parameters for $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$.
We proceed by induction on $d := \dim(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y})$. If $d = 0$, then $X$ is the closed fiber of $f$, and hence it has at most terminal singularities by assumption.
Now suppose $d > 0$. We apply the inductive hypothesis twice.

By the inductive hypothesis, the Cartier divisor $f^{-1}(V(x_d))$ has at most terminal singularities. Thus, $X$ has at most terminal singularities in a neighborhood of $f^{-1}(V(x_d))$ by [Nakayama 2004, Chapter VI, Theorem 5.2(2)] (which I showed implies the case of arbitrary $k$ of equal characteristic zero [Murayama 2022, Proposition 4.15]).
It remains to show that $X$ has at most terminal singularities in the complement of $f^{-1}(V(x_d))$. First, all fibers of $f$ have at most terminal singularities by [Murayama 2022, Corollary 4.18(i)]. Thus, since $\dim(\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}[x_d^{-1}]) < d$, the inductive hypothesis applied to the complement of $V(x_d)$ shows that $X$ has at most terminal singularities in the complement of $f^{-1}(V(x_d))$.

We conclude that $X$ has at most terminal singularities. $\blacksquare$
Remark. Over the complex numbers, the same proof works for canonical singularities using [Kawamata 1999] and for terminal or canonical pairs using [de Fernex and Hacon 2011, Proposition 3.5(b)].

I believe you can get a result for stacks by base changing to smooth covering by schemes. Note that the property of having at most terminal singularities is smooth-local by [Kollár 2013, Proposition 2.15].
Corollary. Let $f \colon \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ be a flat finite type morphism of integral algebraic stacks locally essentially of finite type over a field $k$ of equal characteristic zero. Suppose that $\mathcal{Y}$ is regular and that all closed fibers of $f$ have at most terminal singularities. Then, $\mathcal{X}$ has at most terminal singularities.
Proof. Let $p\colon V \to \mathcal{Y}$ be a surjective smooth 1-morphism from a scheme $V$. Consider the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
  U @>q>> V \times_{\mathcal{Y}} \mathcal{X} @>p'>> \mathcal{X}\\
  @VVgV @VVf'V @VVfV\\
  V @= V @>p>>\mathcal{Y}
\end{CD}
$$
where the right square is 2-Cartesian and $q\colon U \to V \times_{\mathcal{Y}} \mathcal{X}$ is a surjective smooth 1-morphism from a scheme $U$.
Now note that the morphism on schemes induced by $g = f' \circ q$ satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem. For the condition on closed fibers, the closed fibers of $g$ are smooth over the closed fibers of $f$, and hence still have terminal singularities. By the theorem, we see that $U$ has terminal singularities. Since $p' \circ q\colon U \to \mathcal{X}$ is smooth, $\mathcal{X}$ has terminal singularities. $\blacksquare$

Thanks Takumi, that's very nice! When X and Y are DM stacks (say over the complex numbers), does a similar argument work, or is the Nakayama result from 2004 (I guess these are called "small deformations"?) only known for varieties?

@caagun I think you can take smooth covers by schemes to reduce to the scheme case, which should be quicker instead of trying to prove everything from scratch. For example, to redo the proof for stacks, one would have to reprove my result on non-closed fibers in (2) for stacks. For your specific question, you can get the analogue of Nakayama's result for stacks by taking smooth covers (although I don't exactly know what a Cartier divisor is on a stack).
